# How can i implement face authentication using biometric prompt in android x?

Tags: android-biometric-prompt

But can i implement face authentication using biometric prompt or any other android api's in my app.
If no, are there any sdk which I can use to implement this feature in my app??

Comment: What is face authentication with biometric prompt ?

Comment: Biometric prompt is a class provided by android and face , fingerprint and iris authentications are provided in that api. but im not sure how i can use face in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the BiometricPrompt class to create a prompt dialog that just uses **any** biometric credential the user has initialized (e.g. fingerprint but also face).
You can create a authentication dialog with the following steps:

#### Step 1: Add dependencies to your build.gradle file in app/

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1'
}
```

#### Step 2: display the authentication prompt

```
private Executor executor;
private BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
private BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(MainActivity.this,
            executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            // authenticated
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
            // authentication failed
        }
    });

    promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric Authentication")
            .setSubtitle("Log in with your biometric credentials")
            .build();
}
```

The dialog will be displayed by calling this method:

```
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
```

Check [the android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth#java) for further information.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please do not line to some source which might not be available forever – at least provide the most important steps here :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks. But ive already implemented this for fingerprint, how do i do the same for face recognition

Comment: It's the same, you don't have to change your code. But as far as I understood there is currently only one device supporting the feature, the Pixel 4. But this will change of course in the near future. You may want to check this video: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=iqr_ySZ5Dus